# Как обрабатывать ключи QMap написанные на русс языке? (Убунту)

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

```
QMap<QString, QString> example {
        {"а", "$$$"},
        {"б", "$$%"},
        {"в", "$%%"},
        {"a", "-1-"},
        {"b", "-+="},
        {"c", "dna"},
        {"d", "dsv"}
    }

ba = text.toLocal8Bit();
         char texter[10000];
         for (col=0;col<=text.length();col++){
              it = example.begin();
         texter[col] = ba[col];

             while(it != example.end()){
                 it++;
                 if(it.key() == texter[col]){
                    hash_string_text += it.value();
                     break;
                 }

                 }
```

С символами на англ.яз - все нормально.
Но если искать ключи написанные на русском, то их не видно.

Comment: Кто он? Приведите нормальный [mcve]. И код текстом, а не картинкой надо приводить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинкой. Поставил минус за плохое оформление вопроса.

Comment: @älёxölüt я не знаю что вам привести еще. Есть QMap с русскими ключами, если я пытаюсь найти в нем русские ключи. Он (QMap) не находит эти ключи. 
Вопрос №1
Как сделать что бы их(КЛЮЧИ) было видно? Чтобы я мог получить значение, обращаясь  к ключу с русскими буквами.

Comment: @AK Второй можете поставить, жалко я вам не могу поставить за плохое содержание ответа.

Comment: По ссылке, которую я дал, вполне должно быть ясно, что от вас требуется привести в вопросе. Почитайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот вам [пример](http://codepad.org/2UjaidP4), где всё работает с русскими буквами.

Comment: @älёxölüt то есть вы вопроса не поняли?

Comment: Вопроса помимо меня не поняли ещё как минимум 4 человека, поэтому ваш вопрос и закрыли, чтобы вы привели его в состояние, понятное другим людям, а не только вам.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь кнопкой [edit] под текстом вопроса для его правки.

Comment: Снял минус и проголосовал за переоткрытие вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details) - это Unicode строка. Вы же сравниваете её не то что со однобайтовой строкой, а вовсе с одиночным однобайтовым символом:

```
if(it.key() == texter[col])
```

Понятно, что такое сравнение не будет никогда давать истину для ключей, которые не представлены одним байтом.

Comment: Может подскажите как решить данную проблему? 
Например как брать каждый символ по очереди из QString и сравнивать его с ключами ,чтобы QMap не ругался потом?

Comment: @cleverclever получить отдельный символ из `QString` можно через [`operator[]`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-5b-5d). Собственно, как и для большинства строковых классов.